# cakephp error Uncaught exception 'LogicException'

Tags: php, cakephp, php-extension

I'm new to cakePHP and I've been having real difficulty getting it working on my free aws account. I first tried setting up LAMP on my own, but gave up and am now trying to use the bitnami LAMP stack:

https://aws.amazon.com/amis/bitnami-lapp-stack-5-4-13-1-64-bit-ubuntu-12-04

Anyways, that seemed to work, and I was following the cakePHP Blogs tutorial:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html

I got the mySQL database and tables all set up, and just to test I went to the cakePHP dir:

http://[my amazon instance].compute-1.amazonaws.com/cakephp/

Page loads up with no problems.

But if I reload that page, I get an error:

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'LogicException' with message 'Passed array does not specify an existing static method (class 'App' does not have a method 'load')' in /opt/bitnami/frameworks/cakephp/lib/Cake/bootstrap.php:133\nStack trace:\n#0 /opt/bitnami/frameworks/cakephp/lib/Cake/bootstrap.php(133): spl_autoload_register(Array)\n#1 /opt/bitnami/frameworks/cakephp/app/webroot/index.php(77): include('/opt/bitnami/fr...')\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in /opt/bitnami/frameworks/cakephp/lib/Cake/bootstrap.php on line 133

At that point, nothing to do but restart apache. Once again the page shows up one time, then reload and it errors as above.

Halp!

Comment: To be clear: I stopped my old aws instance where I was rolling my own stack and created a brand new one with the bitnami stack.

Comment: So after creating a new instance, did that solve your problem?  In my 7-8 years of working with PHP, I have never seen that error before.  However, after a small Google search, I saw it may be related to short tags. Although CakePHP does not use short tags, and I dont remember seeing any short tags within the tutorials, its still possible that you are using short tags on your own.  Check your ini settings if that is the case.

Comment: Hi, so the bitnami LAMP was installed on a fresh instance. All I did was deploy the instance with the bitnami LAMP stack, and attempt to follow the cakePHP tutorial.